# How to ensure that samplers are executed in same order in jmeter

Tags: rest, jmeter

I have a thread group, lets say ThreadGroup1 which contains four samplers for testing REST services. Lets Say, Sampler1, Sampler2, Sampler3, Sampler4. If I use single thread, then these samplers run in same order like,

*Sampler1-->Sampler2-->Sampler3-->Sampler4*

But, if I choose multiple threads, lets say 10, then this order becomes random. I want to execute them in same order. I tried checking consecutive level at Test Plan level, but that didn't help.

Comment: Samplers will get executed always in same order as you define it in Jmeter. It is random threads which execute the samples.

Comment: Ahh...you mean even if they appear to be in different order in results, still they were executed in order. Good observation. Thanks.